# How to locate household for event participant

Tags: search, custom-search

We organize a yearly week where children come to our community center to play and have fun. All children are entered and linked to their household, which is also where we put all contact-information for the parents such as phone numbers and e-mail address.
We would like to send an e-mail to the parents of last year's participants, inviting them to sign up their children for this year's event but I can't figure out how to do that with the available search options.
Is this something that I can only fix with a custom search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used the "relationship" section of the Advanced Search in conjunction with the "event" section to find the related households of participating individuals?

Comment: After fiddling with this I managed to get it to work; just too bad that the saving of smart groups from Advanced Search is broken in 4.7.9.
Eventually I ended up creating a smart group with the search builder that has all the children in it that attended our event in the past year and are not too old to attend this year. Next I did an Advanced Search for households where the members are in the previously created smart group.